# Issue with positioning SKSpriteNode in SKScene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

This is my first project with SpriteKit and I am following [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQ15rvwSFt8) tutorial
But when I try to give the position to the Image as he did into that tutorial at **20:10** with this code :

**playScene.swift**

```
import SpriteKit

class playScene : SKScene {

let runningBar = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    println("We are at the new scene!")
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0x80D9FF, alpha: 1)
    self.runningBar.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.runningBar.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - (self.runningBar.size.height / 2))
    self.addChild(self.runningBar)

}
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

    }
}
```

I want to give position at bottom of the screen but I got this Output:

[image]

But the output should be:

[image]

**GameScene.swift** (If needed)

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

let playButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "play")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    self.playButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.addChild(self.playButton)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0x80D9FF, alpha: 1)

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches{
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.playButton{
            var scene = playScene(size: size.self)
            let skView = self.view as SKView!
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
            scene.size = skView.bounds.size
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }

    }

}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me how can I achieve this?

Thanks In advance.

Comment: post the code related to creating the bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the tutorial properly. You have set the following lines wrong:

```
self.runningBar.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
self.runningBar.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - (self.runningBar.size.height / 2))
```

They should be:

```
self.runningBar.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5)
self.runningBar.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + (self.runningBar.size.height / 2))
```

For a better understanding of the coordinate system, have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html).

Comment: How about `anchorPoint = CGPointZero` and `position = CGPointZero`?

Comment: Dharmesh, you could also implement it the same way as commented by @0x141E